# Ran2 prng library compatible with C++ "random" distributions

Tags: c++, class, random, std

I've looked for it a lot and even though it is referred as a good prng in term of quality, except for the cycle length of less than 10^63, I didn't found anything.

There are a lot of strange looking prng out there, all of these in huge libraries compatible with "random" and C++11 standards; none of these has ran2.

The first question popping out of my mind is: why?
The second question is: is it possible? I really need to compare the results of that one with other prngs for the system I'm simulating (Ising Model), which is said to be a little infamous with prngs and behaves well with ran2.

I already have the library which implements it in a C++ way https://github.com/PrincetonUniversity/athena-public-version/blob/master/src/utils/ran2.cpp, but I hope to find a way to use it with uniform real distributions too.

Comment: “…a good prng in term of quality, except for the cycle length of less than 10^63”  Really? Do you realize that if you generated a billion values per second it would take 10^54 seconds to complete it’s cycle, which translates to ~3E32 times the current age of the universe? Cycle length will never be a problem for you.

Comment: well, that was the comment of a scientific paper i found and that's the reason why I'm ok using it. Anyway there were a little problems with it and most of prng full cycles are really long, so i think the issue is not about how much time you spend to finish the cycle, but how much time you spend to come near the end. There could be really not good behaviors there and i'm not studying cryptography or those subjects, so i just know that it's not really good and seeing the trends of good prng i'm quite sure it has something to do with it.

Comment: My point is that you will ***never*** come anywhere close to “the end” of the cycle if it’s 10^63. You may have other reasons to not use this particular PRNG, but saying the cycle length may be insufficient is not a legitimate criticism. For non-crypto use, statistical properties become far more important than cycle length once you get into cycles that would take many billions of years to enumerate.

Comment: So, then, why didn't anyone created a Ran2 library compatible with distributions in random library of C++?

Comment: I'm not saying you are wrong, I'm just looking for this library.

Comment: Be aware that questions seeking library recommendations are explicitly off-topic. [See item number 3 on this page of the site help docs](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Meanwhile, questions such as “why didn’t anyone create…?” are pointless as they get into other people’s motivations, which could vary all over the map. Maybe someone did, and you haven’t found it? Maybe nobody did because it’s hard, or they felt it wasn’t worth their time? Maybe because existing solutions become standardized or entrenched and are hard to dislodge even when better technologies come along?

Comment: It is from Numerical Recipes, I believe. https://www.astro.umd.edu/~ricotti/NEWWEB/teaching/ASTR415/InClassExamples/NR3/legacy/nr2/CPP_211/recipes/ran2.cpp